# ThemeData primarySwatch attribute cannot use my custom MaterialColor

Tags: flutter

I am creating my own MaterialColor like so:

```
Map<int, Color> pokeballRedSwatch = {
  50: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.1),
  100: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.2),
  200: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.3),
  300: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.4),
  400: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.5),
  500: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.6),
  600: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.7),
  700: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.8),
  800: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 0.9),
  900: Color.fromRGBO(238, 21, 21, 1.0),
};
MaterialColor pokeballRed = MaterialColor(0xffee1515, pokeballRedSwatch);
```

I am using it like so:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: pokeballRed,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/title.dart': Failed assertion: line 24 pos 15: 'color != null && color.alpha == 0xFF': is not true.
```

However, when I replace the `primarySwatch` with this:

```
Map<int, Color> pokeballWhiteSwatch = {
  50: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.1),
  100: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.2),
  200: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.3),
  300: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.4),
  400: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.5),
  500: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.6),
  600: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.7),
  700: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.8),
  800: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 0.9),
  900: Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 1.0),
};
MaterialColor pokeballWhite = MaterialColor(0xfff0f0f0, pokeballWhiteSwatch);
```

It runs fine.

As far as I can tell, the color is not null, and the alpha byte in both cases if 0xff, as it should be. Any ideas where I am going wrong, or should I open an issue for Flutter on github?

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly rebuilding the application fixed my issue. Still unsure why this fixed it, as I wrote all of these at the same time, and hot reloaded to test each one.

Comment: it happens some times. Tech is so weird :P

Answer (score 0):

add withAlpha in end this line

```
    MaterialColor pokeballRed = MaterialColor(0xffee1515, pokeballRedSwatch).withAlpha(255);
```